# How can you increment a number on scroll without having the scrollbar(actually scrolling)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, imagine 2 sections/divs (both with `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`). I only see the first section, the second section is to the right side of the screen, unable to be seen(overflow: hidden; on the body).

Now, when I scroll, I want that second section to appear gradually, with each pixel I'm "scrolling".

But, the problem here is, I can't actually scroll, thus properties such as this: `window.pageYOffset`, `element.getBoundingClientRect()` do not work. Basically, I want to increment a number each time I do a scrolling gesture, so I can assign that number to the second section( to modify its left property so it can come in the viewport ). And I don't know how to increment the number.

This is a recreation of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```js
var secondSection = document.getElementsByClassName("second-section")[0];



function leftTransition(){
   /*secondSection.style.left = number to be incremented + "px";*/ 
}

document.addEventListener("scroll", leftTransition);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.first-section, .second-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.second-section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-section">
  content
  content
 </div>
 
 <div class="second-section">
  content
  content
 </div>
```

Comment: this recreation does nothing - so - hard to tell, because I'm not good at imagining :p

Comment: Why not continue using percentages? + or - 1% each scroll?

Comment: Because technically, the scroll event does not fire, because there's nothing to scroll. I'm really confused to what I should do now.

Comment: Either resize the page so there's always something to scroll or choose a different event. Maybe you can do something with the `wheel` event which will fire when a mousewheel is rotated. And since the basic functionality on desktop is to scroll the page, it's a good alternative. Just be sure to provide some kind of  fallback. It's generally not a good idea to use scrolling events if there's nothing to scroll.

Comment: I think @Shilly's right about the `wheel` method, I would recommend looking at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel#Listening_to_this_event_across_browser) for it

Comment: Question: what if the user does not have a mouse wheel? Or uses a laptop (trackpad)? Or one of those newfangled smart phones that don't have a mouse at all?

Comment: When devving for mobile devices, you have to change plenty of events already. Click becomes touchstart/touchend, scroll become swipe etc. So basically you hook up those functions to the respective mobile events as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go for the `wheel` event, something like this might resemble what you're trying to do.
You can then remove the event handler once the page is as much in view as you want.

```js
var secondSection = document.getElementsByClassName("second-section")[0];
function leftTransition( event ){
  var offset = event.deltaY;
  var left = offset < 0
    ? ( parseInt( secondSection.style.left ) + 1 ) + '%'
    : ( parseInt( secondSection.style.left ) - 1 ) + '%';
  secondSection.style.left = left;
}
window.addEventListener("wheel", leftTransition);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.first-section, .second-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: steelblue;
}
.second-section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-section">content content</div>
<div class="second-section" style="left: 100%">content content</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted, but I have a question before I'll accept the answer
how can I, if I scroll "up" for example, make the second section go back into its original state?

Comment: The `event.deltaY` property will be positive when scrolling down and negative when scrolling up. Maybe there's different properties or methods you can use as well, but have a look at the wheel event reference Matthew posted.

Comment: That's great! Thank you.